# Webpack dev server for vue-cli: Error spawn EACCES

Tags: node.js, webpack, centos, vue.js, virtualbox

My environment:

- Centos7 via VirtualBox (installed on Windows7)
- Node version: 6.10.3
- Npm version : 3.10.10
- I'm behind a corporate proxy

I initialized a new project "vuetest" with vue-cli, and now I want to run a webpack server.
I use the following command:

```
npm run dev
```

This command is equivalent to "webpack-dev-server --open --hot", here is my "package.json" file to check:

```
{
  "name": "vuetest",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
> vuetest@1.0.0 dev /var/www/html/vuetest
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /dist/
404s will fallback to /index.html
internal/child_process.js:319
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/vuetest/node_modules/opn/index.js:75:24)
    at reportReadiness (/var/www/html/vuetest/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:424:3)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/vuetest/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:404:4)
    at Server.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1284:10)

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! vuetest@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vuetest@1.0.0 dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vuetest package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vuetest
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vuetest
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/vuetest/npm-debug.log
```

Here's the contents of the "npm-debug.log" file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.10.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~predev: vuetest@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~predev: no script for predev, continuing
7 info lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: vuetest@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/vuetest/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/bdupre/.local/bin:/home/bdupre/bin
10 verbose lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /var/www/html/vuetest
11 silly lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot' ]
12 silly lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle vuetest@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
14 verbose stack Error: vuetest@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid vuetest@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /var/www/html/vuetest
17 error Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
18 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
19 error node v6.10.3
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error vuetest@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vuetest@1.0.0 dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vuetest package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs vuetest
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls vuetest
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Does anyone know how to fix it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
In the "package.json" file, I replaced:

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot"
```

By this :

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --port 8080 --hot --host 0.0.0.0"
```

And now everything works, my server, starts up normally.

Answer (score 1):

node_modules/opn/xdg-open is not executable, if you're on linux this is what fails at opn/index.js line 75

or add this

```
    console.log(cmd, args, cpOpts);
```

before line 75 in node_modules/opn/index.js to see exactly which command fails

Answer (score 1):

As Emil said, this is a problem with opn module, because xdg-open is not executable.
I have the same problem in a project generated with vue-cli, that uses opn 5.1.0.

Simply doing `chmod +x node_modules/opn/xdg-open` will solve this. But each time node module is updated this change will be lost.

I ended up commenting the call to opn in build/dev-server.js:

> if (autoOpenBrowser && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'testing') {
>
> ```
>  //opn(uri)
> ```
>
> }

and opening manually my browser on http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

can you check if the port 8080 for your dev server is already in use? Just hit http://localhost:8080 in your browser or change the port in the webpack.config.js and try again. I had a similar issue, maybe thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Checking at your trace log, this problem occur into module opn, exactly in line 75 of index.js

`Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/vuetest/node_modules/opn/index.js:75:24)`

looking in that file, we see:

```
 50         } else {
 51                 if (opts.app) {
 52                         cmd = opts.app;
 53                 } else {
 54                         cmd = path.join(__dirname, 'xdg-open');
 55                 }
 56 
 57                 if (appArgs.length > 0) {
 58                         args = args.concat(appArgs);
 59                 }
 60 
 61                 if (!opts.wait) {
 62                         // xdg-open will block the process unless
 63                         // stdio is ignored even if it's unref'd
 64                         cpOpts.stdio = 'ignore';
 65                 }
 66         }
 67 
 68         args.push(target);
 69 
 70         if (process.platform === 'darwin' && appArgs.length > 0) {
 71                 args.push('--args');
 72                 args = args.concat(appArgs);
 73         }
 74 
 75         var cp = childProcess.spawn(cmd, args, cpOpts);
```

Probably node is trying to run `xdg-open` which is a bash script so it needs execution permission.

Try :

`chmod a+x xdg-open`

or, if you are in the root of your project:

`chmod a+x node_modules/opn/xdg-open`

PS: Usually all these files have correct permissions. In a deseperate situation you always can delete directory `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Important PS: Usually all these files have correct permissions. In a deseperate situation you always can delete directory node_modules and run npm install again.