# webpack-dev-server module throws "spawn EACCES" error

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Until recently everything worked fine. Now, all of a sudden, `webpack-dev-server` throws an error.

My **webpack.config.js** looks like this:

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ["./src/js/app.js"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/js/"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    open: true
  }
};
```

My scripts in **package.json** looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "babel src -d dist && webpack-dev-server --inline --hot",
    "build": "gulp uglify"
  }
```

The error that `webpack-dev-server` module throws when executing `npm run dev` is:

```
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
internal/child_process.js:325
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EACCES
```

and then it exists immediately (terminal is ready for new commands).

I've already searched on google `webpack-dev-server spawn EACCES error` but without proper results. I've even tried running the scripts with `sudo` command, but it still doesn't work.

I can't seem to find what am I doing wrong.

Comment: perhaps a similar issue is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504208/webpack-dev-server-for-vue-cli-error-spawn-eacces). Does the accepted answer there work?

Comment: I'll check it out.

Comment: I've added `cross-env NODE_ENV=development` in the script, now it throws `sh: 1: cross-env: not found`. Maybe I have issues with the OS itself.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot about that bit. Did you try `webpack-dev-server --port 8080 --hot --host 0.0.0.0"`?

Comment: Yay, it works! Can you please post that as an answer, so I can upvote and verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I cannot claim credit for this answer (source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625226/8436941)), but since it worked for the OP I am posting for reference/future researchers.*

The solution is to specify the port as `0.0.0.0`:

```
webpack-dev-server --port 8080 --hot --host 0.0.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

check if node_modules/opn/xdg-open is executable

Comment: Making node_modules/opn/xdg-open executable fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js had no execution rights when I tried to build for production. Adding them fixed it. Even fresh npm install wouldn't fix it.